# Build In prototype functions like Array.map, Array.filter VS _.map, _.filter

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Can somebody explain to me what's difference between array's prototype function like map,filter,reduce and underscore's function *.map,*.fiter,_.reduce.

we can solve problem by using array.map, array.filter and array.reduce. however why underscore function's mostly used?

Please suggest any link or tell me proof of concept.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think @ouroborus answers your main question, Arrays and Objects are different, and underscore's map,forEach, and reduce are for using against Objects (not arrays)

Some of the functions you mention until recently just not part of the core ECMAScript/JavaScript even for Arrays. Libraries were created by coders who got tired of rolling their own over and over. But, they also didn't want to mess with prototypical changes to the core objects they operated on. Without going into each function, Mozilla's documentation lists what revision of ECMAScript the function was added.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

One note. some frameworks like angular for example, also re-implement things like `.forEach`, however some of these cases are to do custom implementation, such as the case with `angular.forEach` where it skips properties starting with `$`.

Comment: _...are for using against Objects (not arrays)_ - that's not true, underscore's `map`/`filter`/`reduce` works for Objects and Arrays. Additionally, although your reference is useful, it's browser-specific and may contain more than ES5 changes, here is another one: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

Answer (score 1):

Generally, underscore's functions operate on lists (objects that can be treated like arrays in some fashion) while the prototypes only operate on the object they're attached to. For example, `_.map()` works on objects (dictionaries) while `Array.prototype.map()` is only callable from arrays.

Comment: Well, good catch. I honestly hadn't really noticed, It became muscle memory to call `_.map()` never really noticed `someObject.map` isn't a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `filter`, `map` and `reduce`.

The following will all result in the same outcome:

```
_.filter([1,2,3], function(n) { return n % 2 });
[1,2,3].filter(function(n) { return n % 2 });
// [1,3]    

_.map([1,2,3], function(n) { return n * 10; });
[1,2,3].map(function(n) { return n * 10; });
// [10,20,30]

_.reduce([1,2,3], function(a,b) { return Math.max(a,b); });
[1,2,3].reduce(function(a,b) { return Math.max(a,b); });
// 3
```

Looking specifically at `map` and the parameters passed to the iterator, they are the same:

```
_.map([1,2,3], function(el, index, array) { ... })
[1,2,3].map(function(el, index, array) { ... })
```

However, already mentioned by other posters, is that Underscore methods work on objects too, but beyond that they also work on *Array-like* objects, from http://underscorejs.org/#each:

> Note: Collection functions work on arrays, objects, and array-like objects such as arguments, NodeList and similar.

Also mentioned by other posters, is that any browser not supporting ES5 (released April 2009) will not provide these default implementations. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

But lastly, there is a feature offered by Underscore, not available in the default implementations, that is the ability to set a **context** in the iterator:

```
var obj = {A: true, B: false, C: true};
_.map(['B','B','C'], function(key) { return this[key]; }, obj);
// [false,false,true]
```

Why might this be useful? Couldn't `obj` be accessed within the function? Yes, it can. The normal use case for passing context is this:

```
_.map([...], function(item) {
    this.parentScopeFunction(...);
}, this);
```

To do this with the default implementations, the pattern is more verbose:

```
var parentScope = this;
[...].map(function(item) {
    parentScope.parentScopeFunction(...);
});
```